# Set specific bit in byte

Tags: java, byte, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to set bits in Java byte variable. It does provide propper methods like `.setBit(i)`. Does anybody know how I can realize this?

I can iterate bit-wise through a given byte:

```
if( (my_byte & (1 << i)) == 0 ){

}
```

However I cannot set this position to 1 or 0, can I?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit)

Comment: @phuclv That is a C/C++ question, not a Java question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel the same syntax is used. If fact the tag should be renamed to something like C-like

Comment: @phuclv The fact it uses the same syntax is - in my opinion - not a sufficient reason to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Use the bitwise **OR** (`|`) and **AND** (`&`) operators. To set a bit, namely turn the bit at `pos` to `1`:

```java
my_byte = my_byte | (1 << pos);   // longer version, or
my_byte |= 1 << pos;              // shorthand
```

To un-set a bit, or turn it to `0`:

```java
my_byte = my_byte & ~(1 << pos);  // longer version, or
my_byte &= ~(1 << pos);           // shorthand
```

For examples, see [Advanced Java/Bitwise Operators](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Advanced_Java/Bitwise_Operators)

Comment: see also the xor operator -- it's the third power-tool in that arsenal (see the Wikipedia article on masking).

Comment: wow. this is actually basic computer science stuff but still mind blown me, binary world are awsome

Answer (score 73):

To set a bit:

```
myByte |= 1 << bit;
```

To clear it:

```
myByte &= ~(1 << bit);
```

Comment: what do you mean this would "set" a bit? say you were trying to access the 0th bit, and myByte contains 11101101. What does this mean? How do I control what the value being set is?

Comment: @Michael: Setting a bit means making it 1. Clearing a bit means making it 0.

Answer (score 30):

Just to complement [Jon‘s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674006/set-specific-bit-in-byte/4674035#4674035) and [driis‘ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674006/set-specific-bit-in-byte/4674055#4674055)

To toggle (invert) a bit

```
    myByte ^= 1 << bit;
```

Comment: @ernesto but it does not specifically answer the question.  He asked how to set the bit, not toggle it.  There is a difference.  Of course, you could check the bit first, then toggle it if needed, but that would be 2 separate tasks as well...

Answer (score 11):

The technique you need is to isolate the chosen bit and either set or clear it.  You already have the expression to isolate the bit since you're using that to test it above.  You can set the bit by ORing it in, or clear the bit by bitwise AND with the 1's complement of the bit.

```
boolean setBit;
my_byte = setBit
          ? myByte | (1 << i)
          : myByte & ~(1 << i);
```

Answer (score 9):

Please see the class java.util.BitSet that do the job for you.

To set : `myByte.set(bit);`
To reset : `myByte.clear(bit);`
To fill with a bool : `myByte.set(bit, b);`
To get the bool : `b = myByte.get(bit);`
Get the bitmap : `byte bitMap = myByte.toByteArray()[0];`

Comment: Careful with bitset. There is no distinction between setting a bit to 0 and clearing it, thus `length()` would not count those bits set to 0