# Change bits value in Byte

Tags: java

I have some data in field type Byte ( I save eight inputs in Byte, every bit is one input ).
How to change just one input in that field ( Byte) but not to lose information about others ( example change seventh bit to one, or change sixth bit to zero )?

Comment: Better use the primitive type `byte`. The wrapper class `Byte` should only be used where needed, e.g. when you want to put bytes into collections.

Comment: Sounds like you'd be better off using a set than an integer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set specific bit in byte](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674006/set-specific-bit-in-byte)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To set the seventh bit to 1:

```
b = (byte) (b | (1 << 6));
```

To set the sixth bit to zero:

```
b = (byte) (b & ~(1 << 5));
```

(The bit positions are effectively 0-based, so that's why the "seventh bit" maps to `1 << 6` instead of `1 << 7`.)

Comment: (This takes advantage of auto-boxing and -unboxing to convert from `Byte` to `byte` and back.  If you're running in an older JVM, you'll have to convert them explicitly.)

Answer (score 14):

Declare `b` as the primitive type `byte`:

```
byte b = ...;
```

Then you can use the compound assignment operators that combine binary operations and assignment (this doesn't work on `Byte`):

```
b |= (1 << bitIndex); // set a bit to 1
b &= ~(1 << bitIndex); // set a bit to 0
```

Without the assignment operator you would need a cast, because the result of the `|` and `&` operations is an `int`:

```
b = (byte) (b | (1 << bitIndex));
b = (byte) (b & ~(1 << bitIndex));
```

The cast is implicit in the compound assignment operators, see the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.26.2).

Comment: Performance-wise, is it true to say that the compound assignment one and the non-compound one is **identical** ?

Comment: Yes, most likely they compile to the same machine code. But I haven't checked, why don't you do that?

Comment: well I'm not even sure what should I Google to learn how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

To set a bit use :

```
public final static byte setBit(byte _byte,int bitPosition,boolean bitValue)
{
    if (bitValue)
        return (byte) (_byte | (1 << bitPosition));
    return (byte) (_byte & ~(1 << bitPosition));
}
```

To get a bit value use :

```
public final static Boolean getBit(byte _byte, int bitPosition)
{
    return (_byte & (1 << bitPosition)) != 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the "Byte" wrapper class is immutable, and you will need to work with "byte".

Answer (score 0):

You really owe it to yourself to look into masking functions for and, or, and xor -- they allow you to simultaneously verify, validate, or change... one, some, or all of the bits in a byte structure in a single statement.

I'm not a java programmer by trade, but it's derived from C and a quick search online seemed to reveal support for those bitwise operations.

See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29) for more information about this technique.