# Set bit values in Byte

Tags: java

I need to set the bit for some of the Bluetooth Features listed below using Java:

```
HeaderValue:BluetoothFeatures, 
Tag ID:0x10, 
Length:4 bytes, 
Possible Values :
    Bit 0 = a,
    Bit 1 = b,
    Bit 2 = c,
    Bit 3 = d,
    Bit 4 = e ....so on till bit 31.
```

Comment: What is your question? Java have bit manipulating operators like `|`, `&`, `<<` etc.

Comment: Bytes have 8 bits, and you are talking about bit 31. Please add more detail to your question.

Answer (score 0):

To set the seventh bit to 1:

```
b = (byte) (b | (1 << 6));
```

To set the sixth bit to zero:

```
b = (byte) (b & ~(1 << 5));
```

(The bit positions are effectively 0-based, so that's why the "seventh bit" maps to 1 << 6 instead of 1 << 7.)

Source : [Change bits value in Byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844342/change-bits-value-in-byte)