# Set the Byte values in java

Tags: java, byte, arrays, bit-manipulation, bit

I want to convert the binary string to byte array in `java` . I have write the code to set every bit of the byte array from the binary string `String A = "1000000111010000"`

```
        private byte firstByte;
    private byte secondByte;
        byte xByte = new byte[2];

        for(int i=0 ; i<A.length() ;i++){

            if(i<8){
                System.out.println(" i : "+i+" A.char[i] :"+A.charAt(i));
                firstByte = (byte) (firstByte | (A.charAt(i) << i));
            }else{
                System.out.println(" i : "+i+" A.char[i] :"+A.charAt(i));
                secondByte = (byte) (secondByte | (A.charAt(i) << i));
            }
        }
        xByte[0] = firstByte;
        xByte[1] = secondByte;
```

To write the above code i have taken the help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674006/set-specific-bit-in-byte) link . 
But the value get stored int the `xByte[0]` and `xByte[1]` is not correct.
It gives values like

```
                   xByte[0] :-15
                   xByte[1] :0
```

Is this is the write way?Please suggest me the correction to get the right byte values.

Comment: `System.out.println((int)A.charAt(i));`

Comment: A.charAt[i] will return a char, not a number and you are setting bit to a char value

Comment: I tried with `(int)A.charAt(i)` but it results same.

Answer (score 5):

Just use [BinaryCodec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/BinaryCodec.html) from Apache Commons:

```
 byte[] bytes = new BinaryCodec().toByteArray("1000000111010000");
```

If you want to do such conversion on your own, your code needs some corrections.
You are expecting that `A.charAt(i)` will return numeric 0 or 1, but will actually return `char` '0' or '1'. The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character with a numeric range from 0 to 2^16, it's values are formally called  [code points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point).
To print the code point value you need to cast char to int:

```
System.out.println("Character " + A.charAt(i) + " has a code point numeric value of " + (int)A.charAt(i));
```

Output for '0' and '1':

```
Character 0 has a code point numeric value of 48
Character 1 has a code point numeric value of 49
```

Operator '<<' [converts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) char operands to int, therefore this shifting is producing wrong results because:

```
firstByte = (byte) (firstByte | (A.charAt(i) << i));
```

is the same as

```
firstByte = (byte) (firstByte | ( (int)A.charAt(i) << i));
```

which for char '0' is the same as shifting value 48 to the left:

```
firstByte = (byte) (firstByte | ( 48 << i));
```

To convert char '0' or '1' to 0 or 1 numeric value use Character.getNumericValue(A.charAt(i)):

```
firstByte = (byte) (firstByte | ( Character.getNumericValue(A.charAt(i)) << i));
```

Also shifting by value `i` is incorrect. You need to shift by `(7-i)` for the first byte or `(7-i%8)` for the second byte. When index `i` reaches 8 it needs to start counting from 0, therefore `i%8`

When printing a values for a byte type you have two options:  byte numeric value or binary string representation:

```
System.out.println("FIRST  byte numeric value = " + xByte[0] + ", binary string representation = " + Integer.toBinaryString((xByte[0]+256)%256));
System.out.println("SECOND byte numeric  value = " + xByte[1] + ", binary string representation = " + Integer.toBinaryString((xByte[1]+256)%256));
```

output:

```
FIRST  byte value = -127, binary representation = 10000001
SECOND byte value = -48, binary representation = 11010000
```

Whole corrected example:

```
public class ByteTest
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    byte firstByte=0;
    byte secondByte=0;

    String A = "1000000111010000";
    byte[] xByte = new byte[2];





    for(int i=0 ; i<A.length() ;i++){

      System.out.println("Character " + A.charAt(i) + " has a code point numeric value of " + (int)A.charAt(i));

      if(i<8){
        System.out.println(" i : "+i+" A.char[i] :"+A.charAt(i));
        firstByte = (byte) (firstByte | (Character.getNumericValue(A.charAt(i)) << (7-i)));
      }else{
        System.out.println(" i : "+i+" A.char[i] :"+A.charAt(i));
        secondByte = (byte) (secondByte | (Character.getNumericValue(A.charAt(i)) << (7-i%8)));
      }
    }
    xByte[0] = firstByte;
    xByte[1] = secondByte;


    System.out.println("FIRST  byte numeric value = " + xByte[0] + ", binary string representation = " + Integer.toBinaryString((xByte[0]+256)%256));
    System.out.println("SECOND byte numeric  value = " + xByte[1] + ", binary string representation = " + Integer.toBinaryString((xByte[1]+256)%256));




  }

}
```

Comment: What you call the numeric value is the character code (formally the code point), the numeric value of the character `1` is actually the number 1. There is a method [Character.getNumericValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28char%29) for accessing it.

Answer (score 4):

You can't simply cast the `A.charAt(i)` to an `int`. It'll return the **ASCII code** of the *1* and *0*.

Therefore, you need to do something like this to get their numeric value:-

```
int bit = Character.getNumericValue(A.charAt(i)); // This will give the actual value
...
firstByte = (byte) (firstByte | (bit << i));
```

Answer (score 1):

A.charAt[i] will return a char, not a number and you are setting bit to a char value.

Instead use

```
if(A.charAt[i] == '0')
  firstByte = (byte) (firstByte | (0 << i));
else
   firstByte = (byte) (firstByte | (1 << i));
```