# Converting a String of Bytes to its Corresponding ASCII Value

Tags: java, byte, ascii, bit-shift, bit

I have a string in java the represents the bits in a byte. For example, I have

```
String mybyte = "00010010";
```

I want to convert this to its actual ASCII value, 'H', and then write it out to File.

I can't seem to get the string to convert to its corresponding ASCII char. Any idea how this is done.

Thanks.

Edit: 
Not sure what code to show since I just have a string that I want to convert to a byte. I'm guessing I need to do some shifting, but I don't know how you would shift it.

Comment: Show your code. Without it we can't tell why your code isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want `(char) Integer.parseInt(string, 2)`.

Comment: No, I've tried this. It doesn't throw an error, but there is no output.

Comment: What do you mean, there's no output?  There's definitely a `char`; what are you doing with it?

Comment: (According to http://www.sciencebuddies.org/science-fair-projects/project_ideas/CompSci_ASCII_Table.shtml, the "actual ASCII value" of the number you've written above isn't actually `H`, it's some control code that probably actually doesn't look like anything when you do `System.out.println` on it.)

Comment: I'm very baffled with no output as well. It's just blank. I try printing that char and absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

my_byte = my_byte | (1 << pos);

I found it here: [Set specific bit in byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674006/set-specific-bit-in-byte)

I was implementing this incorrectly before and hence my post. My apologies for repeating something that has previously been asked.