# How do you flip a specific bit in a Java primitive byte?

Tags: java, binary, byte

I have never used bytes in Java before, so I am unfamiliar with the sytnax for manipulating bytes and bits. I searched how to do this task, but I can't find a simple solution.

I have a byte b. b has eight bits. I would like to flip the ith bit of b to its negation (0 -> 1, 1 -> 0). How do I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4677641/14955

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set specific bit in byte](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674006/set-specific-bit-in-byte)

Comment: Try `(byte)(b ^ (1 << i))`.

Comment: I don't understand this answer's notation of what i and bit stand for.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work:

```
byte b = 0; // initial val ...0000000
final int theNumberofTheBitToFlip = 2; // bit to flip
b = (byte) (b ^ (1 << theNumberofTheBitToFlip));
System.out.println(b); // result ...0000100 = 8
b = (byte) (b ^ (1 << theNumberofTheBitToFlip));
System.out.println(b);// result ...0000000 = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int i=3; 
b = (byte) (b ^ (1 << i));
```